# JSON Parse error: Unable to parse JSON string in React Native

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, react-native

I am having trouble trying the parse this JSON data. I can fix this error by limiting my data to just one like this: `{"id": "13", "imagename": "hello"}`, but this is my whole data:

```
{"id":"1","imagename":"dog"}{"id":"2","imagename":"cat"}{"id":"3","imagename":"mouse"}{"id":"4","imagename":"deer"}{"id":"5","imagename":"shark"}{"id":"6","imagename":"ant"}
```

I think React Native cannot handle no more than one data in `<Text>`?

```
     export default class HomeScreen extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props)
{

  super(props);

  this.state = {
  isLoading: true,
};

componentDidMount(){
     fetch(`http://www.example.com/React/data.php`, {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
   }).then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {

      data = responseJson;
      this.setState({ loading: false });


   }).catch((error) => {
     console.warn(error);
   });

}

renderItems() {
  const items = [];
  this.data.foreach( ( dataItem ) => {
    items.put( <Text>{ dataItem.id }</Text> );
  } )
  return items;
} <--- This is an attempt to try to put them in an object and then display the data, but I keep getting undefined.

render() {


    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }


      return(

         <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>
          <View>
           <Card>          
              <View>
              <Text>{this.data.id}</Text>
              <Text>{this.data.imagename}</Text>
             </View>
           </Card>
           </View>
         </View>
       );
     }
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#333',
  },
     }
```

I also looked up other parse error questions, but our code is very different. Like I said before, this code works if the data is limited to one. I can't figure out why it does not allow more than one data to be displayed.

EDIT: When I changed my `response.json` to text, I got no results so that could be a reason. When I changed `<Text>{this.data.id}</Text>` to just this.data, I can see all of the data. How do I get just the id from that data?

Comment: Probably because your objects are not separated by commas and in an array.

Comment: Are you sure your JSON is formatted correctly? What you supplied is not an array or delimited with commas.

Comment: @TobyOkeke I was thinking that too and I tried: `this.data = responseJson.join(', ');`. This still didn't fix the error.

Comment: @AnthonySherratt  I believe so, it does display when I limit all of the data to just one set. But an error more than one.

Comment: After the join it should be a csv string. Did you make it an array?

Comment: @TobyOkeke in my .php file it was `json_encoded` and echoed as is. I think this made it into an array.

Comment: That doesn’t necessarily work. Please show the result of using the join function

Comment: `undefined is not a function(evaluating 'response.Json.join(', ')')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the JSON as the notation of an object, containing an array, containing objects:

```
'{"images" : [{"id":"1", "imagename":"dog"},{"id":"2", "imagename":"cat"},{"id":"3", "imagename":"mouse"},{"id":"4", "imagename":"deer"},{"id":"5", "imagename":"shark"},{"id":"6", "imagename":"ant"}]}'
```

Comment: Where do I insert the brackets? In the json file or JS? @Rounin

Comment: The string in the answer above is an example of JSON.

Comment: But React Native won't allow objects in the `<Text>`

Comment: JSON isn't an object - it's a string.

Comment: I see, I just don't know what you would do to place `{images:}` and the square brackets around the JSON data.

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake - it should be `"images" :` rather than `images :`. Corrected above.